# Is it possible to have a point annotation view that can be dragged OR selected?

Tags: ios, mapkit, drag, mkannotationview

I have a `MKMapView` that shows some `MKPinAnnotationView` objects.
I want to be able to drag an annotation view, but I want also to be able to select it.

The problem:

When I implement the delegate function

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {…}
```

this function is immediately called **when I touch down** to the annotation view. It shows an alert, and thus prevents the annotation view from dragging.

When I do not implement the delegate function, I can drag the annotation view as expected.

I think the following should be possible:
- Touch down to the annotation view.
- When I drag, move the annotation view.
- Else, i.e. **when I touch up** from the annotation view, select it.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

My pin annotation view does not have a callout. Rather, when it is selected, it shows an `UIAlertController` so that the user can choose further actions.  If so, the `mapView` is dimmed an is not accessible.

The behaviour that I want to implement is:

If i touch the pin annotation view (finger down), nothing should happen.

If I then move the finger (still down), the pin annotation view should be dragged. If I then lift the finger, the pin annotation view will **not** be selected.

If, however, I do not mode the finger, but simply lift it, The pin annotation view **will** be selected (and the alert view should be shown).

I hope this  clarifies the situation.

Comment: A couple of clarifications, by "shows an alert", do you mean that a callout is being displayed when the annotation view is selected? Also, when you say "touch up" do mean when you lift your finger (as oppose to touch down)?

Comment: I see the selection of an annotation and dragging as two distinct actions. Using a standard pin annotation view, you would select the pin to see the callout and then select the pin again to begin dragging. If the user doesn't want to drag the pin, then they can just select the pin to see the callout.

Comment: Sorry that my question was not clear. I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to handle the dragging yourself and utilize a long press gesture to manage the actions you desire (such as when to display an alert).

This solution is built around **Rob's** detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39374717/4748172) and adds some additional logic to handle the specifics of your question (namely the `wasMoved` instance property).

```
private var startLocation = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
private var wasMoved = false

func handleLongPress(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = sender.location(in: mapView)

    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        startLocation = location
    case .changed:
        wasMoved = true
        sender.view?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: location.x - startLocation.x, y: location.y - startLocation.y)
    case .ended, .cancelled:
        if wasMoved {
            let annotationView = sender.view as! MKAnnotationView
            let annotation = annotationView.annotation as! MKPointAnnotation

            let translate = CGPoint(x: location.x - startLocation.x, y: location.y - startLocation.y)
            let originalLocation = mapView.convert(annotation.coordinate, toPointTo: mapView)
            let updatedLocation = CGPoint(x: originalLocation.x + translate.x, y: originalLocation.y + translate.y)

            annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            annotation.coordinate = mapView.convert(updatedLocation, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Here is my alert!", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(ok)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        wasMoved = false
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

And your `mapView(_:viewFor:)` delegate method would look like:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard let reusablePin = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "Pin") as? MKPinAnnotationView else {
            let pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Pin")

            // Add the long press gesture recognizer to the annotation view
            let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(_:)))
            longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0
            pin.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

            return pin
        }

        reusablePin.annotation = annotation
        return reusablePin
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer (+1). Due to Xmas, I need a few days to test it i my app. Sorry for the delay, Reiner

Comment: @ReinhardManner No worries. The answer could use some refactoring, however it should work based on my testing (Xcode 8.2, Swift 3 and iOS 10).